# PSD of the sum of two zero-mean white noise signals

Tags: fourier-transform, power-spectral-density, white-noise

I am trying to solve the following exercise, where $y(t)$ is the sum of two signals $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ with each of them being the product of the convolution of $e_i(t)$ with $h_i(t)$.

[image]

So far I have found that the PSD of $y(t)$ is equal to
$|H_1(\omega)|^2\sigma_1^2 + \rho\sigma_1\sigma_2[H_1(\omega)^*H_2(\omega) + H_1(\omega)H_2^*(\omega)] + |H_2(\omega)|^2\sigma_2^2$. I am stuck on (c), is there any way that I can do without the conjugates so I can get $2\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2|H_1(\omega)H_2(\omega)|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $A$ and $B$ complex, $|A|^2 = AA^*$ and $(A+B)^* = A^*+B^*$

You need to show that
$$|H_1 + H_2|^2 = |H_1|^2 + |H_2|^2 + H_1^*H_2 + H_1H_2^*$$

Well:

\begin{align}
|H_1 + H_2|^2 &= (H_1+H_2)(H_1+H_2)^*\\
&= (H_1+H_2)(H_1^*+H_2^*)\\
&= H_1H_1^* + H_2H_2^* + H_1^*H_2 + H_1H_2^*\\
&= |H_1|^2 + |H_2|^2 + H_1^*H_2 + H_1H_2^*\\
\end{align}